# solid state drive corrupts with sudden power loss

Tags: power-management, ssd, crash, data-corruption

running xubuntu 14.04. I have a kingsoft ssd installed. When there is an unexpected power loss the drive gets corrupted causing me to have to re install. I read that unplugging the drive (of course) prevents data loss but this obviously is not practical since I would still need to plug it back in when I load a new program and would be frustrating to open the case every time I boot. Is there a linux program that will turn off power to the SSD until it is required to be accessed? I feel if there was something like this it would stop the majority of these issues. I have set the power manager to auto shut down at low power, however the issue still arises when the pc freezes and I need to hard shut down.

Comment: SSD are not meant to stand by i have no clue why you want to turn it off. when it uses 0 power when its not being used to start with..... i see no need to turn off power to the SSD.  unexpected power loss will corrupt any file system on a Drive. i think you need to trouble shoot where this sudden power loss is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for a "safely remove" option like with USB drives. The SATA spec is technically capable of this, but I haven't heard that it's ever been implemented for internal drives. However, using a journalling file system such as ext4 should solve your problem.